# Importing `@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-runtime` into AWS Lambda function with Nodejs18 runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-bedrock

I'm trying to import `@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-runtime` into an AWS Lambda function using NodeJs18 runtime.

This package should be available, because according to AWS docs, "For Node.js versions 18 and later, the Lambda Node.js runtime includes the AWS SDK for JavaScript version 3." source: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-aws-sdk-latest-version

When I try it with DynamoDB:

`import { DynamoDBClient, ListBackupsCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";`

I get no errors.

But with Bedrock:

`import { BedrockRuntimeClient, InvokeModelCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-runtime";`

I get `"errorMessage": "Cannot find package '@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-runtime' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"`.

Is there something different about the Bedrock api that prevents it from being imported into Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Node18 Runtime includes SDK version [3.362.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html).

`@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-runtime` was added in [3.422.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/releases?q=%22client-bedrock-runtime%22&expanded=true), you'll need to add it manually.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can find that information? I'd also like to know which version of the SDK is included in the Node20 runtime

Comment: @EricM It's the same as Node18 but the 3.362.0 link is a page with the Lambda runtime info.